# Multiple Manual Mocks of CommonJS Modules with Jest

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I saw the documentation for Jest's mocks using the **mocks** folder, but I want to be able to mock a module with one mock in one test and mock that same module with another mock in another test.

For example, with rewire and jasmine, you could do something like this:

```js
//module2.js
module.exports = {
    callFoo: function () {
        require('moduleToMock').foo();
    }
};

//module2Test.js
describe("test1", function () {
    var mock;
    beforeEach(function () {
        var rewire = require('rewire');
        mock = jasmine.createSpyObj('mock', ['foo']);
    });
    it("should be mocked with type1", function () {
        mock.foo.and.returnValue("type1");
        rewire('moduleToMock', mock);
        var moduleUsingMockModule = require('module2');
        expect(moduleUsingMockModule.callFoo()).toEqual("type1");
    });
});
describe("test2", function () {
    it("should be mocked with type2", function () {
        mock.foo.and.returnValue("type2");
        rewire('moduleToMock', mock);
        var moduleUsingMockModule = require('module2');
        expect(moduleUsingMockModule.callFoo()).toEqual("type2");
    });
});
```

Is this possible to do with Jest? The difference is I define the mock within the test, not in some external folder that is used for all tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your mock will look like this:

```js
module.exports = {
    foo: jest.genMockFunction();
}
```

Then you will be able to configure a custom behaviour in your test cases:

```js
var moduleToMock = require('moduleToMock');

describe('...', function() {
    it('... 1', function() {
        moduleToMock.foo.mockReturnValue('type1')

        expect(moduleToMock.foo).toBeCalled();
        expect(moduleUsingMockModule.callFoo()).toEqual("type1");
    });

    it('... 2', function() {
        moduleToMock.foo.mockReturnValue('type2')

        expect(moduleToMock.foo).toBeCalled();
        expect(moduleUsingMockModule.callFoo()).toEqual("type2");
    });
});
```

Comment: Note that the boilerplate is strongly reduced with jest :)

Comment: Thanks this makes a lot of sense!

Comment: As of [Jest 15](https://facebook.github.io/jest/blog/2016/09/01/jest-15.html#disabled-automocking), you now need to explicitly mock the module also. Add `jest.mock('moduleToMock') before requiring it.