# Jest: Change output of manual mock for different tests within a test suite

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

Let's say I have the following two files:

```js
// index.js
...
import { IS_IOS } from 'common/constants/platform';
...
export const myFunction = () => (IS_IOS ? 'foo' : 'bar');


// index.test.js
...
import { myFunction } from './index';

jest.mock('common/constants/platform', () => ({ IS_IOS: true }));

describe('My test', () => {
  it('tests behavior on IOS', () => {
    expect(myFunction()).toBe('foo');
  });

  // --> Here I want to change the value of IS_IOS to false

  it('tests behavior if NOT IOS', () => {
    expect(myFunction()).toBe('bar');
  });
});
```

As you see my mocking function returns `IS_IOS: true`. I want it to return `IS_IOS: false` after my first test. How would I do that?

---

I also tried an adaptation of [the solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28639662/multiple-manual-mocks-of-commonjs-modules-with-jest#answer-28740117) but I couldn't get it work, because there the mock returns a function:

```js
module.exports = {
    foo: jest.genMockFunction();
}
```

whereas my mock should return a boolean value which is not called inside the file I'm testing.
That's what I did here:

```js
// common/constants/__mock__/platform
export const setIsIos = jest.fn(val => (IS_IOS = val));
export let IS_IOS;

// index.test.js
...
import { IS_IOS, setIsIos } from 'common/constants/platform';
jest.mock('common/constants/platform');

describe('My test', () => {
  setIsIos('foo');

  it('tests behavior on IOS', () => {
    expect(myFunction()).toBe('foo');
  });

  setIsIos('bar');

  it('tests behavior if NOT IOS', () => {
    expect(myFunction()).toBe('bar');
  });
});
```

Oddly when console-logging, i.e. `console.log(IS_IOS);` I get the expected values. The test however seems to use the original value, i.e. `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

Add `jest.resetModules()` to the `beforeEach()` call of that `describe()` test suite:

```
describe('EventManager', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
  });
  ...
```

Additionally I found A more complete example on how to mock modules with jest [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2582#issuecomment-346886018)